# Big O notation for halving substrings in a string of length n

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, runtime-analysis

I am trying to do some runtime analysis on a problem, but get stuck on some details.

I have a string $P$ of length $n$, where I am allowed to halve substrings inside of it and keep the right-hand side of it to form new strings. We can now halve substrings in the new string. The length of the substrings that are halved must be even. The goal is essentially to "count" in how many ways I can halve a string to a single character.

An example string is $P = hello$. Two examples of how it can be halved:

1. "he" can become "e", which yields $P = ello$. We can now halve "ello" such that $P = lo$, and halve "lo" such that $P = o$.
2. "hell" is halved to "ll", which yields a new string $P = llo$. Here, either "ll" is halved (new string is $P = lo$), or "lo" is halved (new string is $P = lo$ as well).

The runtime must depend on $n$ somehow, but since the total length decreases with each operation, I feel like it must depend on $\log n$ or something similar.

Comment: Sorry, can you make the problem a little clearer? You are given a string, and you can halve it, but what's your objective for doing this step? Do you continually halve the string until it becomes a single character?

Comment: @Russel sorry, yes. I need to ”count” in how many ways I am able to halve it down to a single character.

Comment: Suppose $P$ is $ccc$. The first $cc$ can become $c$, which yields $cc$. Or the $cc$ at the end can become $c$, which yields $cc$. Are there two ways or one way for $P$?

Comment: The assumption is that those are different, i.e., two ways @JohnL.

Comment: Does the answer depend on the string, or just on its length?

Comment: Well, the big O notation should only depend on the length @YuvalFilmus.

Comment: Does the thing that you’re counting depend on the string, or just on $n$?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to make the question be clear and  read well for someone who encounters it for the first time and contain all the information needed to answer the question, rather than adding clarifications in the comments.  Perhaps you could tell us where you encountered this task and what is the motivation or original source for it.  Thank you!

Comment: What are the correct results (number of ways) for let's say the strings "abcd" and "aaaa"?

Comment: You vaguely described the *problem*, but not a complete *algorithm* for *solving* the problem. Are you asking about the runtime of the *problem*?

Comment: @KellyBundy yes, I want the runtime of the problem. And "abcd" and "aaaa" are "equal" in the runtime, i.e., suppose that in "aaaa" all are ways of halving are distinct.

Comment: Problems don't have runtimes. Solutions (algorithms) do. Or do you mean the limit for how fast it *can* be solved? You'd be asking for big Omega instead of big O then, though.

Comment: What *is* the result for abcd and aaaa? Being equal is good to know and I think answers Yuval's question, but knowing the number would still help to more clearly understand the task.